# Bootstrap CSS navbar height huge in IE&FF, Correct in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using BootStrap3 CSS navbar. In my jsfiddle demo, it works fine between Chrome and FF&IE, but on the site, FF&IE have a huge bar/blank space below the menu. I can't seem to find the problem using the FF element inspector. If I disable my theme style, it fixes some of it, but it's still large, so there's perhaps some conflict there. I've disabled most everything I can think of, but still cannot figure out the conflict or what I'm doing wrong.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MECU/mbjMv/3/) vs [Website](http://rockyprep.com/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2013/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Year </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#year-navs"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="year-navs">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2007/">2007</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2008/">2008</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2009/">2009</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2010/">2010</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2011/">2011</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2012/">2012</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/football/colorado/team/mountain_range/2013/">2013</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Really Large in FF]

It should only be 52px (or so) tall.

What am I doing wrong? Where's the conflicting CSS? Am I not using/installing the Bootstrap CSS correctly?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong yet, but I'm seeing this problem across the board in Mac browsers. PS what do you mean, 'correct in FF, wrong in FF'?

Comment: @JeremyCarlson "Correct in FF" should have been "Correct in Chrome". I have corrected it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out, and then it was painfully obvious:

Your sidebar is floated left. The `navbar` is clearing floats so it contains them all gracefully (all of the nav elements within are floated), but since it's not within a floated element, it is clearing **all** the floats around it.

You will need to add `float: left` (or `float: right`) to a containing element so the `navbar` does not try to clear floats outside of that container.

You have `<div style="margin: 0 0 0 170px;">` in your code which seems to be the relevant container.

Instead, try a negative left margin, left padding to compensate, and 100% width:

```
<div style="margin: 0 0 0 -170px; float: right; padding-left: 170px; width: 100%;">
```

You probably should move that to your stylesheet, but I bet you knew that.

Comment: This solves the problem, but in IE (v8), all the content is now moved below the floated sidebar. FF is now correct. Chrome was having the same problem as well, but is now correct. IE also thinks it's in a small window as it has the navbar collapsed.

Comment: It does seem to be fixed in IE 9/10, so this may just be a legacy IE8 issue then.

Comment: I don't have IE8 in front of me at the moment. But you might try messing w/ the negative margin, or adding CSS inside an IE8-targeting conditional comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience in this field, but I may have a solution for you. Just add a constraint height: 52px; to .navbar class in your css.

Comment: I tried that too, but it causes problems with the navbar when it's collapsed and tries to expand. Without wanting that responsiveness, this would work.